# Web scrape with python | Limited objects

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to get data from a website that uses pc parts, and I have this link that have over 3500 parts on that page, the problem is that if I use the clean link:
  https://www.komplett.no/search?q=pc

it only get the data that is there before I scroll down and it loads new items.

So I took the link edited like this:
  https://www.komplett.no/search?q=pc&hits=1000

Now it gets all the info from over 1000 products but I can't go over that because the script just don't want to work, I don't get an error or anything. 
BTW, I only get the things on sale so its not that much data.

I want a way to go through the hole page without having to write the limit to how many products I want to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how I would approach this web scraping task:

It looks like when you scroll to the bottom there are 24 new items added to the page. Since I see there are 3919 results when we filter by `pc`, let's use a headless browser/JavaScript engine like PhantomJS and tell it to scroll to the bottom of the page and then wait a few seconds for the new results to load, and repeat that number of process of 3919/24 times. For this to work you would need to install a webdriver like PhantomJS

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.komplett.no/search?q=pc')
num_pages = int((3919/24) + 1)
for _ in range(num_pages):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
 
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Once you have finished the loop, you can call `.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')` to capture the html of currently loaded on the DOM tree and then do you the rest of the web scraping with that data.

btw, I did a PC scraping project a while ago, [here's the link](http://briancaffey.github.io/2017/01/01/pc-data.html) if you want to check it out.

Comment: you could probably save time by starting at https://www.komplett.no/search?q=pc&hits=1000

Comment: @EvenLauvrak hey no problem. If the solution worked for you could you mark the answer as accepted? Otherwise let me know if you need more help. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sure man i will accept it. Il lett you know if theres anything more.